# Spotbugs - Null pointer dereference issue on Optional

Tags: java, null, option-type, dereference, spotbugs

I have simple case, but struggle to understand what is wrong, seems that optional is checked, however Spotbugs sees this as null pointer dereference. Tried orElseThrow() as well, same thing.

```
package com.bam;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class Check {

    @NotNull
    public Integer check() {
        Optional<Integer> integer = find(3);
        if (integer.isPresent()) { 
            return integer.get(); // here Spotbugs finds Null pointer dereference
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("number not found!");
    }

    private Optional<Integer> find(Integer number) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(1);
        set.add(2);
        return set.stream()
                .filter(integer -> integer.equals(number))
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Optional` has an API method for this specific use case:

```
return find(3).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("number not found!"));
```

You say you "tried `orElseThrow`", but you didn't post the message you say you're getting from SpotBugs, and since that method cannot return null, if you *are* getting one, that's a bug in SpotBugs.